# PHP script hangs while performing bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell, mono, exec

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to an NFC payment terminal. I have successfully sent transactions via the command line. When I try to use the exact same thing in PHP using exec() or system() it hangs. 
 
What is supposed to happen is the following: I send a command with url, price in cents, and the timeout it needs to wait for confirmation **after** payment is done. 
 
I press enter, the command gets sent and after ~4 seconds the payment request appears at the payment terminal. I tap it with my NFC card and it says 'APPROVED' in the Raspberry Pi console. Now I need to confirm it by pressing 'c' or it gets voided. I don't really care about the last part at the moment, but that is taken care of as well. The command I send is a .exe file, but it is working using mono. 
The command that I use is:

```
printf 'c' | mono /home/pi/Desktop/PayterPay/PayterPay.exe -u $url -a $price -t $timeout
```

This works, as described above. printf 'c' is to take care of the confirmation, which also works. 
Now I want to use it in a PHP script, so I try

```
$command="printf 'c' | mono /home/pi/Desktop/PayterPay/PayterPay.exe -u $url -a $price -t $timeout"; 
exec("$command", $out, $return_code);
```

However, when running this script, it will hang/wait for around a minute. Then it continues as normal, I get the payment, I pay, it gets confirmed, and it verifies that it is indeed confirmed. 
I assume this has something to do with the way system() and exec() (I tried both) handle commands, but I don't understand why there is such a long delay. What is so different between running straight from the commandline and using my PHP script?

### TL;DR

I run a 'mono' command via exec() and system(), it has a delay of around a minute. This does not happen on the command line, nor does  a delay take place when issuing a different command. Aside from that it does everything it should. How to get rid of this delay?

### UPDATE:

If I run the script from the commandline it runs just fine. Running it in the browser causes a long delay. I figured it might have something to do with the fact that via the browser it is run via user www-data. But switching to www-data in the commandline and running the script still works without delay. So I guess that is also not the reason why it is lagging.

Comment: Try to add a newline: `printf '%s\n' c | mono ...`. Also, you should escape the CLI arguments with `escapeshellarg()`.

Comment: I added the newline but it did not help. What was the intended effect? 
And I should escape the CLI arguments, as in 'best practice' or as in 'otherwise the code won't work properly' ?
I am not allowing my users to input arguments so that should be a moot point.

Comment: You should escape the arguments in order to prevent interpretation of special characters by the shell and thus to prevent unexpected behavior

Comment: Try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/22a0b6328da839193b84f2bef875a106)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help, it works (just like my script), but the delay is still there. When I run the php script (yours or mine) from the command line it works just fine, but opening it in the browser causes the long delay. I'll update the description with some more info I found.

Comment: Most likely `PayterPay.exe` is causing this behavior. Maybe you have configured a proxy in the shell environment which is not available for the webserver environment. I guess, it is somehow related to DNS resolution.